# CSS file from external server. Where are referenced images being pulled from?

Tags: css, cross-browser, cdn

This feels like a very dumb question that should be obvious to me. ;)

If we have our site `www.example.com` but we're pulling our CSS files from a cdn domain `www.examplecdn.com` if we have this in said css file...

```
.sample {background url('/images/myimage.gif')}
```

...which server will the browser request the images from? Is it consistent from browser to browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848147/image-paths-in-css-to-support-cdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is related to where the CSS is stored. So in this case the remote server would be the one asked for the image.

Comment: That's what I thought...but I just wasn't fully confident of it. Thanks!